# deleting excel tabs doesn't reduce file size

Tags: excel

In an effort to reduce a 60MB excel file I deleted half the tabs, and many of the formulas on the remaining tabs.
The result didn't budge the overall filesize.  Perhaps (as in access) there's a function/addin/?  which will compress or recover the space?
I tried to export the tabs to a new file, however, most of the tabs have tables and so is impossible.

btw, the file is already in .XLSB format.
thank you,
-R

Comment: Delete what appears to be blank rows and columns.

Comment: no wonder, since this is a site for programmers.

Comment: Google "excess format cleaner"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my liposuction code I wrote years ago, it will do formulas, text and pics, doesn't do charts currently but you can see how it handles pics and add that in easily enough.

```vb
Sub LipoSuction2()
'Written by Daniel Donoghue 18/8/2009
'The purpose of this code is to offer an alternative to the original Liposuction code written by JBeaucaire for the MrExcel forums www.mrexcel.com
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As String
Dim OldSheet As String
Dim Col As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim BottomrRow As Long
Dim EndCol As Long
'Begin addition 6/4/2010 for request: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?p=2269274#post2269274
Dim Pic As Object
'End Addition 6/4/2010 for request: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?p=2269274#post2269274
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    'Put the sheets in a variable to make it easy to go back and forth
    CurrentSheet = ws.Name
    'Rename the sheet to its name with TRMFAT at the end
    OldSheet = CurrentSheet & "TRMFAT"
    ws.Name = OldSheet
    'Add a new sheet and call it the original sheets name
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = CurrentSheet
    Sheets(OldSheet).Activate
    'Find the bottom cell of data on each column and find the further row
    For Col = 1 To Columns.Count 'Find the REAL bottom row
        If Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row > BottomRow Then
            BottomRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    Next
    'Find the end cell of data on each row that has data and find the furthest one
    For r = 1 To BottomRow 'Find the REAL most right column
        If Cells(r, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column > EndCol Then
            EndCol = Cells(r, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End If
    Next
    'Copy the REAL set of data
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(BottomRow, EndCol)).Copy
    Sheets(CurrentSheet).Activate
    'Paste everything
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    'Paste Column Widths
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    'Begin addition 6/4/2010 for request: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?p=2269274#post2269274
    Sheets(OldSheet).Activate
    For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        Pic.Copy
        Sheets(CurrentSheet).Paste
        Sheets(CurrentSheet).Pictures(Pic.Index).Top = Pic.Top
        Sheets(CurrentSheet).Pictures(Pic.Index).Left = Pic.Left
    Next
    Sheets(CurrentSheet).Activate
    'End Addition 6/4/2010 for request: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?p=2269274#post2269274
    'Reset the variable for the next sheet
    BottomRow = 0
    EndCol = 0
Next
'Excel will automatically replace the sheet references for you on your formulas, the below part puts them back
'This is done with a simple reaplce, replacing TRMFAT with nothing
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    Cells.Replace "TRMFAT", ""
Next
'Poll through the sheets and delete the original bloated sheets
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If Not Len(Replace(ws.Name, "TRMFAT", "")) = Len(ws.Name) Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next
End Sub
```